# Form not passing values on POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's my view code:

```
@model pedidosOnlineMVC.Models.ViewModel.AdmView
@using pedidosOnlineMVC.Models
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Administrador/_LayoutAdm.cshtml";
    List<Usuario> lu = pedidosOnlineMVC.Controllers.UsuarioController.favoreds(Model.adm.estabelecimento.Estabelecimento_Id);
}
@using (var f = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form()))
{
    using (var p = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Panel())) 
    {
        using (var t = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Table())) 
        {
            using (var h = t.BeginHeader()) 
            {
                using(var hr = h.BeginHeaderRow())
                {
                    @hr.Cell("Usuário")
                    @hr.Cell("Status")
                }
            }
            using(var b = t.BeginBody())
            {
                for(int i=0;i<lu.Count;i++)
                {
                    using(var c = b.BeginRow())
                    {
                        @f.FormGroup().CustomControls(Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Usuario_Id[i], lu[i].Usuario_Id))
                        @c.Cell(lu[i].nome)
                        @c.Cell(f.FormGroup().CustomControls(Html.Bootstrap().CheckBoxFor(model=>model.checkAuts[i])))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        using (var pf = p.BeginFooter())
        {
            @f.FormGroup().CustomControls(@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.adm.Administrador_Id, Model.adm.Administrador_Id))
            @f.FormGroup().CustomControls(Html.Bootstrap().SubmitButton().Text("Autorizar"))
        }
    }
}
```

And I had a similar problem here: [cshtml page not passing date value on post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952370/cshtml-page-not-passing-date-value-on-post), but what I did then doesn't work here.
I tried looking in the network window in the developer tools and I can see the ID values (`Administrador_ID` and `Usuario_ID`) being sent on post, but they never reach my controller.
Here's the code for the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult autCli(AdmView adm)
{
    return null;
}
```

It has no code in it because I still didn't get it to work, but the parameters should still work when debugging, but I get NULL in every attribute instead.
If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it.

AdmView model, as requested:

```
public class AdmView
{
    public Administrador adm { get; set; }
    public Produto prod { get; set; }
    public virtual List<bool> checkAuts { get; set; }
    public virtual List<int> Usuario_Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that view name is autCli?

Comment: Yes.
The code reaches the controller, as I said, but the AdmView object attributes are all NULL when it does.

Comment: Please post your `AdmView` model.

Comment: Why do not you use the FormCollection for passing data?

Comment: I don't know what the is

Comment: Can you add the generated html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection(v=vs.100).aspx) to pass data from view to controller.

**Just like this:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult autCli(FormCollection collection)
{
  strint Usuario_Id = collection["Usuario_Id"]; //You can get data with this way...
  return View();
}
```

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995285/how-to-access-my-formcollection-in-action-method-asp-net-mvc) for more info.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it. I can't do it right because my laptop crashed yesterday, but as soon as I get it running again I'll do it.

Comment: Did you crash your laptop because this problem getting you angry? :)

Comment: Alright! Finally got it working, and `FormCollection` did the trick. Thank you. I promise not to beat up my laptop next time my code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add `[HttpPost]` before your ActionResult method.

Comment: It has it, sorry, it got cut out in the ctrl+c